# Is the CDF of the INID Maximum Order Statistic always equal to the Product of CDFs?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let there be a set of random variables $\left\{ X_0, \ldots, X_{N} \right\}$, that are independent  but not identically distributed.

Will the equality:

$$F(X_0 \leq x) F(X_1 \leq x) \cdots F(X_N \leq x) = P( X_0 \leq x, X_1 \leq x, \ldots, X_{N} \leq x) = P( X_{\left( N \right)} \leq x ) $$

always hold?

I think I'm being confused by the definition of the lower order statistics requiring us to sum over all the permutations of the joint probabilities and their possible sequencings.

So it makes sense to me that for the maximum order statistic we should also permute over all possible sequencings of orderings.

So the equality should hold only when the random variables are exchangeable right? But I haven't found any good examples of a set of random variables that are both independent and not exchangeable. Or a set of INID random variables whose maximum order statistic is not equal to the CDF of the joint probability.

Maybe someone can help me with a counter example in either case?

Comment: What on earth is INID ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Independent but Not Identically Distributed. I realized I wasn't clear about my definition of joint distribution too. I meant the scenario where the CDF of the joint distribution is equal to the straight product of all the CDFs without needing to consider all possible sequencings.

Comment: Let $(X_\ell)_{1\leq \ell \leq n}$ be mutually independent random variables. Then
$$\begin{aligned}P(X_{(n)}\leq x)&=P(\max(X_1,...,X_{n})\leq x)=\\
&=P(\cap_{1\leq \ell \leq n}\{X_\ell \leq x\})=\\
&=\prod_{1\leq \ell \leq n}P(X_\ell\leq x)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @Snoop is there never a scenario when $$P(X_1 \leq X_2 \leq x) \neq P(X_2 \leq X_1 \leq x)$$ When the random variables are independent?